# How to add a new line after each loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Currently getting this output

```
[1, 1, 3, '\n']
[1, 1, 3, '\n', 7, 7, 7, '\n']
```

looking for this output

```
[1, 1, 3]
[7, 7, 7]
```

Code:

```
    import random
    my_list=[]
    n = 3
    m = 1
    while m < 10:
    for i in range(n): # repeats the following line(s) of code n times
        my_list.append(random.randrange(0,9))
    my_list.append("\n")
    print(my_list)
    m = m+1
```

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific?  You want the outcome to look a certain way while printing?? I looks like you want a 2d array then.

Comment: @reticentroot Trying to create a file of random numbers for testing (3485, 6758, 8094) but each set of 4 numbers on a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random
n = 3
m = 0
my_list = []
while m < 10:
    my_list.append([])
    for i in range(n):
        my_list[m].append(random.randrange(0, 9))
    print(my_list[m])
    m = m + 1
```

This code creates sublists inside `my_list`, and prints out each sublist every iteration. So your output might be something like this:

```
[0, 4, 8]
[3, 1, 5]
...
[9, 2, 5]
```

but `my_list` would store all the sublists, like this: `[[0, 4, 8], [3, 1, 5], ..., [9, 2, 5]]`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Neil It looks like you want a 2d array.  Here's another way to do it.

```
from random import randint

my_list = [[randint(1, 11) for i in xrange(10)] for j in xrange(randint(5, 10))]
```

This will create a 0 - 9 number object 5 to 9 times. e.g [[2,3,4,5...], [1,2,2,3...]...]

Then you just iterate over the object to print it out the way you want

```
for item in my_list:
  print item
```

**UPDATE**

Given the comment you replied with here is example of a random number file generator.

```
from random import randint

#number of lines to create on the file
n = 3
with open('my_file.txt', 'w') as cout:
  for i in xrange(n):
    cout.write('{0}\n'.format(randint(1000, 10000))) #this is exclusive so it will only go as high as 9999
```

If you want more numbers on each line format the text inside the write method. E.G

```
cout.write('{0}, {1}\n'.format(randint(1000, 10000), randint(1000, 10000)))
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a logic to remove duplicates numbers if any?

Comment: Instead of using a list use a set.

Answer (score 1):

Put the my_list=[] inside the outer loop to reinitialize it each time. Also, if you don't want the newline, don't append it to my_list. If you want all the output on the same line use the optional arg `end` to the print function.

```
import random
n = 3
m = 1
while m < 10:
    my_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        my_list.append(random.randrange(0,9))
    print(my_list, end="")
    m += 1
```